# How to use foreach to subtract multiple values with same number in php?

Tags: php, foreach

> I have one scenario where i am having one default value but in
>   foreach loop i have to change that default value to subtract its next
>   value : For example:

I have one scenario in my code where i want something like below
 example :

Suppose I am having total 3 numbers:

1. 4500 **(this is my default value)**
2. 2000
3. 3000

   In foreach loop i am having first value 4500. Now in *`first iteration`* i will do subtraction of first and second value

   *`i.e : 4500 - 2000 = 2500`*

   Now,

   on `*second iteration*` of loop I want result of first iteration *`i.e. 2500`*
   And then i will check if result is greater than or less than of third
   value 3000  according to i will do subtration. like : 
   *`3000 - 2500 =500`*

   SO, Now In *`third iteration i want 500 to be my default value.`*

and so on.

Comment: What would have been the result if the three values were 1) 4500 2) 2000 3) 2000 ? This will help in understanding your underlying logic.

Comment: then too it will do same like above logic: 4500 - 2000 = 2500 and then in       second iteration it will check first iteration's result i.e `2500` and then it will do same logic if else condtion and then 2500 - 2000  = 500

Comment: can you provide the existing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want, it is quite simple. Just do something like so:

```
$values = [2000, 3000];
$default = 4500;

foreach($values as $value) {
    if($value < $default) {
        $default = $default - $value;
    } else {
        $default = $value - $default;
    }
}

return $default;
```

And, if you want it as a function, it is also simple:

```
function finalValue($default, $values) {
    foreach($values as $value) {
        if($value < $default) {
            $default = $default - $value;
        } else {
            $default = $value - $default;
        }
    }
    return $default;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply let me check once with your solution

Comment: i just tried with your code but it stops after first iteration because of return so i remove return and try with normal variable but its not working for third iteration

Comment: means its not working for 3000. it takes default value 4500 for second iteration too

Comment: I don't know if I am following exactly. But you realize that I've removed the default value from the array, correct? If you give another example, I can understand what you want.

Comment: you got me what i want but your code works only for first iteration. i want that on each foreach loop my default value should be different and that will come from previous for each iteration

Comment: @amitsutar, actually, the `$default` value is changed after each interaction on the loop, and then reused on the next iteration. For me, the return is 500, as you wanted in your question. But if this is not the case, I am not fully understanding what you want. Sorry.

Comment: Yes exactly i want like you said default value will be changed for each iteration. but in my code its not working. i dont know what is happening with my code thanks for your answer bro let me check once again